# Big O estimate with loop and recursion

Tags: performance, recursion, time-complexity, big-o

```
     void call(int n)
       {
         for (int j=1;j<=n;j++)
         {
           call(n/2);
          }
       }

     void main()
      {
        int i;
        for (i=1;i<=n;i++)
         {
           call(i);
         }
       }
```

I want to determine the best big-o estimate for this function. My approach is main function is O(N). I think the call function is O(N*LogN). would the total time complexity be O(N^2 Log N)?

Answer (score 0):

Big O estimation is calculated as below:

***call*** method:
the input is ***n*** an there is a loop in the function so O(N)
the recursion is estimated as below

```
T(n/2) -- T(n/4) -- T(n/8) -- T(n/16) ... O(logn)
```

so the call method is nlogn

***main*** method

```
1*call(1) -- 2call(2) -- 3call(3) -- ncall(n) since call(n) is O{nlogn) so n^2logn
```

Comment: I was thinking, would the call function actually be O(n^log n) as each recursion also has (n/2) for loops which call for the recursion?

Comment: Yes it actually is O(n^log n) since the recursion is based on n which is the input of the call function an at each iteration a fraction of the n is passed for the base recursion function.